# Installing CPLEX on Mac: No Java virtual machine could be found

Tags: java, macos, jvm, cplex

I try to install CPLEX on my Mac. When I open terminal and type

`chmod +x /Users/MarjoleinKroon/Downloads/cplex_studio126.osx.bin`
`/Users/MarjoleinKroon/Downloads/cplex_studio126.osx.bin`

I get the following error

> Preparing to install... 
>   Extracting the installation resources from the installer archive... 
>   Configuring the installer for this system's environment... 
>   /Users/MarjoleinKroon/Downloads/cplex_studio126.osx.bin: line 2374: Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java: No such file or directory 
>   /Users/MarjoleinKroon/Downloads/cplex_studio126.osx.bin: line 2374: Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java: No such file or directory 
>   No Java virtual machine could be found from your PATH
>   environment variable.  You must install a VM prior to
>   running this program.

I searched the internet to solve this problem, and I found several things to check. If I type `java -version` I get

> java version "1.8.0_40" 
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_40-b27)
>   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.40-b25, mixed mode)

So it seems like java is installed properly. Furthermore, when I type `/usr/libexec/java_home -V`, a VM seems to be there:

> Matching Java Virtual Machines (1):
>       1.8.0_40, x86_64:   "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home
>   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home

Online I read something about PATHs, but I have not enough knowledge to understand this exactly. However, if I type `echo $PATH` I get

> /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/texbin

I don't know what this means, but it seems kind of strange to me.

Can anyone help me? Please be as clear as possible, because I don't have a lot of knowledge concerning this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can anyone please help me? It's important for my study..

Comment: When you type a name of a program and that program just works, it probably is included in the PATH environment variable. When you want to run a program, usually you need to be in the directory the program is installed. If that directory is added to the PATH environment variable, then it's contents are acessible anywhere on the machine.

Regarding your problem you dont have the JavaAppletPlugin installed. You have a JRE installed but not a JavaAppletPlugin. See if you have that directory on your machine: Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java
can you cd into it?